# How to make MS Virtual PC 2007 start automaticaly?

Tags: virtualization

I tried to find the option in MS Virtual PC 2007 to start everytime I boot windows, but did not found such function. 
Should I write some type of script for that, or would be a better way to make this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to get Virtual PC to start as a service. I have a group policy object for the users that only use a Virtual PC (all training users, booting dummy envionments). Group policy setting:

```
User Configuration
    Administrative Templates
        System/Logon
            Run these programs at user logon
```

The setting is Enabled with the following item to run at logon:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Virtual PC\Virtual PC.exe" -startvm "C:\Virtual Machines\Virtual Workstation.vmc" -singlepc
```

That will start Virtual PC 2007 with a single workstation running.

If you don't want the user to have to login to the host PC before the virtual machine will start, set the folloing keys in this registry path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

```
DefaultDomainName (REG_SZ) = [Domain] (Vista Only)
DefaultUserName (REG_SZ) = [Username]
DefaultPassword (REG_SZ) = [Password]
AutoAdminLogon (REG_DWORD) = 1
```

If AutoLogonCount exists, delete it.

Comment: It worked like a charm in the Win7. Great answer, tks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just put it into the autostart folder?

And if you want to start a virtual computer, just put a link to the corresponding .vmc file into the autostart folder.

Just go to the .vmc-file, select 'create shortcut' from the file menu and move the shortcut file to the autostart folder.

Comment: Everyone seems to have forgotten about the good old Startup folder!!

Comment: Not that simple guys.... because the startup folder will start the application, but NOT the virtual machine.

Comment: Also, this happened when I added the .vmc: 

An error occurred while processing the command line options.
A virtual machine with the same name has already been added to the Virtual PC Console.

Comment: This error happens if you create a copy of the file instead of a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I've stuck a .vbs script in the win startup folder with:

Set objVS = CreateObject("VirtualServer.Application")
Set myVPC = objVS.FindVirtualMachine("myVPCNAME")

myVPC.Startup()

Comment: Hmmm, probably it will work, but I have no idea about vb script.

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch (.bat) file with this in it:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Virtual PC\Virtual PC.exe" -pc "YourVMNameHere" -launch

Pop that in your startup folder and Bob's your uncle.